How do I allow decimal numbers in this program?
class QuadraticFormula:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def quadraticFormula(self):
        try:
            root1 = (-(self.b)+((self.b ** 2 - (4 * self.a * self.c)) ** 0.5)) / (2 * self.a)
            root2 = (-(self.b)-((self.b ** 2 - (4 * self.a * self.c)) ** 0.5)) / (2 * self.a)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return "\nVariable A cannot be equal to 0."
        else:
            if (self.b ** 2 - (4 * self.a * self.c)) == 0:
                return f"\n\nThe one real root of the Quadratic Graph with variables {self.a}, {self.b} and {self.c} is {root1}."
            elif (self.b ** 2 - (4 * self.a * self.c)) > 0:
                return f"\n\nThe two real roots of the Quadratic Graph with variables {self.a}, {self.b} and {self.c} are, {round(root1, 2)} and {round(root2, 2)}."
            elif (self.b ** 2 - (4 * self.a * self.c)) < 0:
                return f"\n\nThe two complex roots of the Quadratic Graph with variables {self.a}, {self.b} and {self.c} are, {(root1)} and {(root2)}."


a = int(input("Enter the variable a of the quadratic equation (ax^2 + bx + c = 0): "))
b = int(input("\nEnter the variable b of the quadratic equation (ax^2 + bx + c = 0): "))
c = int(input("\nEnter the variable c of the quadratic equation (ax^2 + bx + c = 0): "))

qf = QuadraticFormula(a, b, c)
print(qf.quadraticFormula())

So how do I allow decimal values (e.g. 4.5) and not allow strings through the input?
I want this to be checked inside the quadraticFormula() formula.

Instead of int use float. If the user enters bad input, it will throw an exception.

I removed part of your question: "Also is there anything else I can do to optimise the program?" We don't do that on Stack Overflow; instead check out [codereview.se], but first please read their How to Ask page since they have some different guidelines.

BTW, you might also be interested in Asking the user for input until they give a valid response as well as the decimal stdlib module.

@001 oh why didn't I think of that

@wjandrea Alright.

@wjandrea I get that the code is sort of working (but very ugly) - but why is pointing out general rules like excessive repetition of code is a very bad thing off topic here? Likewise for numerical precision weaknesses (and arguably that is a real code/algorithm defect). Though not one that the OP is aware of. Catastrophic cancellation when b>>a,c takes no prisoners for root1 as written.

@Martin It's because "anything else" is too broad. As you're pointing out, there are lots of things that could be improved, but Stack Overflow is meant for specific questions.

@Martin BTW, there were some code style problems with the original code, but I edited them to make it easier to read; Code Review would cover that, but Stack Overflow is about function, not form.
